# Electron application - Icon not displaying

Tags: electron, icons

I have the following code for an eletron-app. when it launches, it comes with the same out-of-the-box generic eletron icon like I didn't provide it my own. The app works as expected other than the icon.

This is a snippet in /src/main.js
I also have "assets" in the src folder.

- src/main.js
- src/assets/logo.ico

```
const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'logo.ico'),
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    });
```

[Eletron Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvR7U.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily change the icon from the default icon during development, however When you build your Electron app, you can follow [this guide](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons) if you are using [Electron Forge](https://www.electronforge.io/).

> ##### [Setting the app icon](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons#setting-the-app-icon)
>
> ###### [Windows and macOS](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons#windows-and-macos)
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>   // ...
>   packagerConfig: {
>     icon: '/path/to/icon' // no file extension required
>   }
>   // ...
> };
> ```
>
> The icon must be additionally loaded when instantiating your
>
> ```js
> const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
>
> const win = new BrowserWindow({
>   // ...
>   icon: '/path/to/icon.png'
> })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To set the icon in development environment you need to specify the proper path for the icon in your BrowserWindow options.

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    // ... other options      
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/logo.ico'),
});
```

The issue I normally face in my Electron applications is that the path is **pointing to the wrong directory** (mostly dist) so make sure to check that.

If you have multiple windows in your application, you'll need to set the path for each windows options.